# .htaccess 301 Redirect: www2 to www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web, http-status-code-301

I want to redirect just one URL:
www2.mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com

I don't want to redirect sub directories, just that top url, if I find another one then I could write another redirect, but I can't seem to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this in the htaccess file in your `www2` document root:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://www.example.com/
```

If the document root is the **same** for both `www` and `www2` then you need to check the HOST header and use mod_rewrite to do that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www2\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: OK I have found an issue today.  I don't want it to redirect if there is a query string:  For example http://www2.c5themes.co.uk/?cID=154 shouldn't redirect to http://www.c5themes.co.uk/?cID=154.  Thanks!

Comment: @DaveReeder add a condition to the rewrite rule: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^cID=154$`

Comment: Thanks Jon, this is what I have:

RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://www.c5themes.co.uk/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^cID=154$

The query string one is still directing from www2 to www, have I added that rule incorrectly?

Comment: @davereeder if you need to match against the query string, you need to use mod rewrite (the second solution)